# How to change OSM map custom theme?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using an osm map, I want to change the map style

How to change the theme colors and styles of the android maps in the open street map- I would like to totally simplify a map for a particular purpose and remove colors of particular elements.

```
binding!!.mapView.apply {

             
                            setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE)
                            zoomController.setVisibility(CustomZoomButtonsController.Visibility.NEVER)
                            setMultiTouchControls(true)
                            val mapController: IMapController = controller
                            mapController.setZoom(12.0)

                            val zoomLocation =  GeoPoint(it.from_lat.toDouble(), it.from_lng.toDouble())

                            mapController.setCenter(zoomLocation)
                            startMarker.position = zoomLocation // marker location

                      

                }
```

[image]

> looking android theme like this screenshot (movie app).
> ** I am looking free solution**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution: will reduce some loading time

```
binding.osmView.apply {


          
      val matrixA = ColorMatrix()
            matrixA.setSaturation(0.3f)
            val matrixB = ColorMatrix()
            matrixB.setScale(1.12f, 1.13f, 1.13f, 1.0f)
            matrixA.setConcat(matrixB, matrixA)
            val filter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrixA)
            overlayManager.tilesOverlay.setColorFilter(filter) // TilesOverlay.INVERT_COLORS
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use MapBox tile source, with a MapBox style that you customize yourself.

Comment: MapBox is costly, i need free or open source solution

Comment: MapBox is free up to a level of usage.